# Download ZIP file in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm writing an app using react-native and I will build it for both android and iOS.
Anyway, I have been trying to download a ZIP-file using react-native but I can't get it to work. After I have downloaded the file my plan is to unzip it and then store it using AsyncStorage. 
But I keep getting the error below:

`[RCTNetworking.m:330] Received data was not a string, or was not a recognised encoding.`

I have tried various settings for my request but I guess I am simply missing something, the code currently looks like:

`fetch('somewhere.path/file.zip', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/zip'
            },
         })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("Success");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error");
        }).done();`

`Success` gets printed but the response data does not contain the zip files data.
If it helps I am debugging using XCode and the simulator.
If anybody has any ideas please help me out! :)

Thanks in advance, 
Yon

Comment: You'll probably have to do this in native code. Fetch doesn't seem to understand `applicaiton/zip` encodings. `not a recognised encoding`

Comment: @rooftop I thought that perhaps it was because I was missing to add some headers or something. Do you know anything I could try?

Answer (score 3):

I also write an app to download some zip files and unzip it. And for download function, I using a plugin called react-native-fetch-blob. Code example:

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
...
RNFetchBlob.config({
fileCache : true,
path: path + '/file.zip'})
.fetch('GET','http://domain/file.zip')
.progress((received, total) => {console.log('progress', received / total)})
.then((res) => {// the temp file path
console.log('The file saved to ', res.path());
});
```

...

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Phuc,Which package are you using for unzipping  the downloaded file?

Comment: Hi @Deepak, I use 'react-native-zip-archive'

Comment: @PhúcHoàngTrương Could you please clarify what path (path + '/file.zip') can I put for iOS and Android? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @anivaler, this is path to your zip file. In my code, I use RNFetchBlob at https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob. You just need scroll to section "File System" for more detail. Thanks,